# open cv cmake can't find png and jpeg

Tags: opencv, png, jpeg

I downloaded opencv 3.2,and run:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python) 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/alex/Software/opencv_contrib/modules 
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON 
-D WITH_JPPEG=ON 
-D WITH_PNG=ON 
-D WITH_CUDA=ON 
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 ..
```

under ubuntu 16.04 got:

```
-   Media I/O: 
....
--     JPEG:                        NO
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         NO
........
```

as you can see that both JPEG and PNG give 'NO',and I hava got libjpeg-dev,libgtk2.0-dev and libpng-dev installed.So how to make opencv to support jpeg and png?

Comment: Does it help if you do this first? `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`

Comment: thanks,same as before